# Logback batch writing to a database

Tags: logback

we have a requirement to record (in a database) each call to one of our methods. However, because of the very large number of times the method is called we want to "batch" the inserts eg. only insert every x seconds or only insert when you have say 100 entries using JDBC batch insert (statement.executeBatch()).

I've understand I can use an Async DB Appender and that this uses an AsyncAppender which uses a Blocking Queue however this seems to be more about blocking the producing thread rather than controlling how often the consuming thread performs an action.

Please could someone advise if my requirement is possible with Logback?

Many thanks

Comment: Looking at the code, DBAppender does not appear to have an option like that. You could copy or extend it to use your own appender. If you're allowed to run a SocketAppender on the machine that hosts the database, you could do that: send the event there and have the DBAppender on that instance.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer Darius, I'll look at using my own appender.